# Parameterizing updates in SQLite in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm attempting to create a wrapper function for an application that will update arbitrary fields in particular row in a sqlite table.  As arguments to the function, I am passing a sqlite connection, an index value to search on, and a dictionary.  This dictionary will contain as its keys the names of the fields to be updated and the updated entries as its values.  I am then stepping through the dictionary and updating the corresponding fields in the table.  So, the code that I want to use looks something like this:

```
def update_mytable(conn, myIndex, data_dict):

    curs = conn.cursor()
    for key, value in data_dict.iteritems():
        curs.execute("UPDATE mytable SET ?=? WHERE key =?", (key, value, index))
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  SQLite appears to complain about the field name being parameterized.  Does anyone have a good work-around for this?  I want the user to be able to change an arbitrary field value without having to resort to opening up a sqlite console.

In response to Martijn's response, I looked more closely at what had already been posted.  Unfortunately, the one with the closest matching title ("SQLite Parameterized Update") was solved through the correction of a typographical error.  So, it wasn't that helpful.  If someone could point me to a post that more closely resembles my problem, I would appreciate it very much.

Thanks!

PatB

Comment: Sorry:  typo.  Those arguments to the executable SQL statement should have been (key, value, myIndex).

Comment: Sorry, again!  My screen scrolled past the article Martijn referred to!  Perfect answer!  Thanks for the response, and, again, my sincerest apologies.